# Возможно ли программно узнать значение параметра FitsSystemWindows?

Tags: android

Для установки размеров контента на весь экран использую:

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

Контент залезает под прозрачный статус бар.

Есть ли способ программно знать какое было состояние до того, как я сделал его false?

Comment: можно узнать размеры любого View через соотв. методы после вызова onWindowsFocusChanged

Comment: Больше контекста. Работаю над  SDK которая представляет собой фрагмент. Мне необходимо раскрыть его на весь экран. Использую  val window = activity?.window ?: return и         WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false). Т.е мне нужно узнать какое значение для fitSystemWindow используется у активити мастер приложения .